# Solr: First facet, then filter query

Tags: solr, filter, duplicates, facet

I am storing documents with text `Content` and with different `Tags`. When searching I am using a filter query to remove duplicates: `q=*:*&fq={!collapse field=Content}`

Next, I want to show the number of documents in each group for which I am using following facet query: `q=*:*&facet=true&facet.field=Tags`

The problem are identical documents which are tagged with different `Tags`. E.g.
I have document `A` indexed four times; twice with tag `x` and twice tag `y`. I want to obtain a table like:

```
+-------------+
| Tag   Count |
+-------------+
| x     1     |
| y     1     |
+-------------+
```

So I tried to combine both queries: `q=*:*&facet=true&facet.field=Tags&fq={!collapse field=Content}`.
However, this will first apply the filter query first and then perform facetting, resulting in:

```
+----------------+
|  Tag   Count   |
+----------------+
| x     0 (or 1) |
| y     1 (or 1) |
+----------------+
```

So, I want to apply the filter query for each facet separately. How is this possible? There is no `facet.fq` parameter. And `facet.query={!collapse field=Content}Tags` gives me `SolrServerException: No live SolrServers available to handle this request`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand correctly you want 'count of unique Content per Tag', correct? if so, [json facets](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceted+Search) will do this:

```
curl http://.../query -d 'q=*:*&json.facet={
   tags:{terms:{
    field : Tag,    
    facet:{        "unique" : "unique(Content)"      }
    }}
}'
```

Comment: Yes, counting unique Content per Tag is exactly what I want. Unfortunately, `json.facet` seems to be obsolete in version 6.6. In the reference guide it is only mentioned in chapter `Upgrading from earlier 6.x versions`. If I try to use it anyways it gives me: `org.apache.solr.common.util.SimpleOrderedMap cannot be cast to java.lang.Number`. Is it possible to do the same with the ``Facet Component`` (https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/faceting.html)?

Comment: absolutely not, json facets are not obsolete. They are preferred over vanilla facets, are newer, and generally better preformers. You are hitting some other issue, double check.

Comment: I do not know what vanilla facets are. But I do not find any documentation about how to use ``json.facet`` for double checking.

Comment: what about the link I already provided in my answer?? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceted+Search

Comment: I tried again, the problem is `"count"` in your answer. It seems that `count` is a reserved name. Please change it e.g. to `"unique"`, so I can accept your answer!

Do you know why the page you linked was not migrated to https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide?

Comment: mmm, unique might be also reserved, that one is working for you? I changed it. No idea about the doc, things are not always totally up to date

Comment: Yes, "unique" is working for me. "Reserved" may have been the word; actually "count" is being used. The result looks like this `... {
          "val":"process",
          "count":11,
          "unique":3},
        {...} ...`